# How would i count all values in my list instead of counting each variable in my list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to count the number of values in my list, but I keep running into the same problem. Everything I have tried only returns the number of characters in each value of my list. Here is what i have so far:

```
with open(csvpath) as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
    
    csv_header = next(csvreader)
    
    print(f"CSV Header: {csv_header}")
    
    for row in csvreader:
        t = (row[0])
        print(t)
        print(len(t))
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of now it keeps listing the count of the variables under each value in my list. For example:  Feb-2020                                                                                                                                  
             8

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to figure out the length of what?

Comment: In your own words, what does `t = (row[0])` do? When you say that you want to find out how many values are in "my list", what is the name of "my list" in your code?

Comment: I am trying to return the number of values in the list. Sorry, if the wording was confusing. And the 't = (row[0])' assigns the first column of the file into the variable t. This is all new to me so that is how I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finding the length of row[0] instead of the length of the row.

Try replacing:
`print(len(t))`

With:
`print(len(row))`

Edit:
I just realized you are trying to count all values in your list instead of each line.
If that's what you're trying to do, use: `len(list(csvreader))` for the length that includes the header, and subtract 1 from that for the number of values in the list

Comment: So I tried this and it returns the length of each specific value in each row. Each of my rows have 8 characters so it just lists a bunch of 8's. I appreciate the answer, though!

Comment: Could you post the format of the data you are trying to iterate through?

Comment: the first picture on this: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/overview.html is the best representation of the data that I am using. However, I am not using pandas.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Can't believe I hadn't thought of that yet, I really appreciate the help on this one!

Answer (score -1):

Another suggestion would be to use python's in-built split function instead of the csv library.
So you could try:

```
with open(csvpath) as csvfile:
    csv_raw = csvfile.read()
    csv_lines = csv_raw.splitlines()

    print(f'CSV Header: {csv_lines[0]}')

    for x in range(1, csv_lines):
        a = csv_lines[x]
        line = a.split(',')
        t = line[0]
        print(t)
        print(len(line))
```